# Reloading a webpage and simulataniously reloading javascript in QT

Tags: javascript, jquery, qt, coffeescript, qwebview

I have a QT-Application which uses a Webpage with Javascript/Coffeescript and JQuery for interaction with the user. In some cases I need to reload the javascript.

However at the beginning of the javascript I set signals to activate javascript methods.

```
$ = jQuery
p = 
  rangeSliders: '#rangeSliders'

m =
  init ->
    d = $.extend {}, p
    mm.connectBackend(d) if typeof StatusBridge is 'object'

mm =
  connectBackend: (d) ->
    StatusBridge.updateAirconLimit.connect (km) ->
    log_debug "receiving aircon limit"
    airconLimit = new KmItem
      value: parseInt(km)
    $(d.rangeSliders).rangeometer('getAirconLimit').trigger 'update', airconLimit
    log_debug "receiving aircon limit done"
```

`log_debug` just prints a message through the internal logging system.

In case there is an error, I trigger the `reload()` slot of the `QWebView`:

```
  bool WebPage::shouldInterruptJavaScript()
  {
     QApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::AllEvents );
     ECONNECT_LOG( Fatal, 108100004, "Javascript has permanent errors" );
     emit requestReload();
     return false;
  }
```

and

```
  QObject::connect( m_webview->page(),
                    SIGNAL( requestReload() ),
                    m_webview,
                    SLOT( reload() ) );
```

in a place outside of the webpage class.

However, whenever the webpage is reloaded, afterwards the callbacks seem to be registered multiple times:

```
2014-Mar-28 13:18:08;GuiBackend;4750;4750;D;108107022;../../src/Gui/StatusBridge.cc:221;Message from javascript: [ receiving aircon limit ]
2014-Mar-28 13:18:08;GuiBackend;4750;4750;D;108107022;../../src/Gui/StatusBridge.cc:221;Message from javascript: [ receiving aircon limit done ]
2014-Mar-28 13:18:08;GuiBackend;4750;4750;D;108107022;../../src/Gui/StatusBridge.cc:221;Message from javascript: [ receiving aircon limit ]
2014-Mar-28 13:18:08;GuiBackend;4750;4750;D;108107022;../../src/Gui/StatusBridge.cc:221;Message from javascript: [ receiving aircon limit done ]
2014-Mar-28 13:18:08;GuiBackend;4750;4750;D;108107022;../../src/Gui/StatusBridge.cc:221;Message from javascript: [ receiving aircon limit ]
2014-Mar-28 13:18:08;GuiBackend;4750;4750;D;108107022;../../src/Gui/StatusBridge.cc:221;Message from javascript: [ receiving aircon limit done ]
```

Is there a way to have QT reload both the HTML as well as the Javascript part? Or is this special about the way QT handles the bindings from C++ to javascript? If so, what would be the best way to reset the webpage in case of crashes?

**Update**

Since this might be important:

I add the C++ Objects to javascript from inside a slot, which gets called in response to the 
`javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()` Signal.